# Client not receiving message from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Hi i have a node js server and im using sockets to communicate.

Index:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Client JS:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8081");

socket.on('hi', function(data){
    console.log("g");
    console.log(data);
});
```

So it seems to connect just fine to the server. I have a socket called 'hi' waiting for any incoming messages. I added 2 console logs incase data was null, it would still print something to the console.

Server:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var mazeGenerator = require("generate-maze");

app.use(express.static("public"));

io.on("connection", function(socket) { // EDITED
    console.log("A player has connected - sending maze data...");
    socket.emit("hi", "hi");        
});
```

So when i refresh the page, the client connects and in my CMD i see the "A player has connected..." console log. From then on, its blank from the server or client, I can keep refreshing and it will keep saying a player has connected by the clients console stays blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the connection is proven to be established, I suspect this is an issue of a way you emit the data. Your second parameter `hi` may not be taken as a data to be transmitted, according to

https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack

In my understanding, `socket.io` emit `Object` instead of `String` so can you try this?

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("A player has connected - sending maze data...");
    socket.emit("hi", {data: "hi"});        
});
```